# SurfaceView with collision

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have the following code in my game (BrickBraker) to check the collsion of the ball with the bar at the bottom. But it stil says that there is a collision even if the ball doesn't hit the bar.

What is wrong with the code I am using below?

```
if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x && ball.x < bar.x + (bar.getWidth()/5)) {
    ...
}

else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + (2*bar.getWidth()/5)) {
    ...
}

else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (2*bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + (3*bar.getWidth()/5)) {
    ...
}

else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (3*bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + (4*bar.getWidth()/5)) {
    ...
}

else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (4*bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + bar.getWidth()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would attempt to check for collision detection between the ball and board:

First we'll check if the ball has "collided" with the board on the x axis. There are three states we'll have to check:

1. The first one being, the ball's left side does not align with the board, yet the right side does.
2. The second being, the ball's left side does align with the board, yet the right side does not.
3. The third one being, the ball's left and right side align with the board.

Here's a image to make it visual:

[image: Example]

This is how we would apply these rules programmatically:

```
// First case
if(ball.getX() + ball.getWidth() > board.getX() && ball.getX() < board.getX()) {

}
// Second case
if(ball.getX() < board.getX() + board.getWidth() && ball.getX() + ball.getWidth > board.getX()) {

}
// Third case
if((ball.getX() + ball.getWidth() > board.getX() && ball.getX() < board.getX()) && (ball.getX() < board.getX() + board.getWidth() && ball.getX() + ball.getWidth > board.getX())) {

}
```

If any of these conditions are met, this means that ball aligns with the board on the x axis. So now we will have to check if they align on the y axis, so we can finally know if they are touching each other.

We can create a method that we can call from any of the if-statements if their conditions are met.

```
public boolean checkYAlignment() {
// Check y alignment
if(ball.getY == board.getY || ball.getY() < board.getY()) {
// The ball and board have collided!
return true;
}
else {
return false;
}
}
```

So now all the code written above put together in the form of a method that will return a boolean value, indicating if the ball and board have collided:

```
public boolean checkCollision() {
// First case
    if(ball.getX() + ball.getWidth() > board.getX() && ball.getX() < board.getX()) {
    return checkYAlignment();
    }
    // Second case
    else if(ball.getX() < board.getX() + board.getWidth() && ball.getX() + ball.getWidth > board.getX()) {
    return checkYAlignment();
    }
    // Third case
    else if((ball.getX() + ball.getWidth() > board.getX() && ball.getX() < board.getX()) && (ball.getX() < board.getX() + board.getWidth() && ball.getX() + ball.getWidth > board.getX())) {
return checkYAlignment();
    }
else {
return false;
}
}
```

I hope this helps and works!

PS: I'm writing this very late, excuse me if I've gotten something wrong, I'll try and correct it as soon possible.

**Update:**

If you want the ball to jump of at an angle when the ball collides with the board, you take the angle that the ball collides with board and let it bounce off at that angle in the other direction. 
There are two ways to do this:

- Use some trigonometry to find the angle.
- You could also simple take the x velocity of the ball and change the
  number to positive or negative eg. if the velocity is negative, then
  make it positive and vice versa.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ty for your answer. but i want the ball to move more to the left if it hits the left side of the board. Thats why i did it like that. Do you have a smart solution for that?